# Как заменить mysqli_fetch_assoc() в PDO?

Tags: php

Вывожу сессию, а она пуста, мне кажется дела в $check_user->fetchAll(), так как я не знаю как в PDO заменить mysqli_fetch_assoc()

```
$check_user = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` =:login AND `password` =:password ");
    $arr = ['login'=>$login, 'password'=>$password];
    $check_user->execute($arr);
    $check_user_row = $check_user->fetchColumn();
    if ($check_user_row > 0) {

        $user = $check_user->fetchAll();

        $_SESSION['user'] = [
            "id" => $user['id'],
            "full_name" => $user['name']
        ];
        
        $response = [
            "status" => true,
            "session" =>$_SESSION['user']
        ];

        echo json_encode($response);

    } else {

        $response = [
            "status" => false,
            "message" => 'Не верный логин или пароль'
        ];

        echo json_encode($response);
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: проблема в бессмысленном вызове fetchColumn(); и в том что fetchAll(); делает совсем другое.

Comment: @Ипатьев А что нужно поставить вместо fetchAll(); ? Я просто многое перепробовал и ничего не помогло

Comment: "пробовать" никогда не надо. надо просто прочитать документацию и использовать ту функция, которая нужна в данном случае. Но если с документацией совсем трудно, то ссылка вверху вопроса